# Jqwidgets rendergridrows

Tags: jquery, widget

please can anyone help me what is rendergridrows supposed to achieve?
I copied the demo but cant seem to customize it for my case.
I have a json data object

```
var data={{usb_data|safe}}//this is a a json object parsed into django template.
i did this



// load virtual data.
var rendergridrows = function (params) {
var data = {{usb_data|safe}};
return data;
}
```

and on initializing the grid i did this

```
$(“#jqxgrid”).jqxGrid(
{
width: ’100%’,
autoheight: true,
source: dataAdapter,
altrows: true,
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
groupable: true,
virtualmode: true,
columnsresize: true,
filterable: true,
rendergridrows:rendergridrows,
```

but it displays an empty grid
can anyone assist me with this please?
Regards
Joshua

Answer (score -1):

rendergridrows should return a JavaScript Array which contains the grid rows

Comment: can you give a code snippet please based on my data?